# Magic Stone + Enlarge

Tags: dnd-5e, magic, house-rules

Can a thrown magic pebble be a target to the *enlarge* spell?  For that matter, can anything from an arrow to a hurled table become *enlarged* while in mid-air and if so how would you suggest fantasy physics would work on this?

The enlarge spell states that the target doubles in all sizes but the weight is times eight.  Would the (stone, for example) maintain its velocity and hit the target with 8x its weight?  We all know that F = m*a.
How would you suggest to handle this DMG wise?

As always thanks in advance my fellow Dungeoneers.

Comment: Heavily related, may contain dupes: [Can the Enlarge/Reduce and Catapult spells be combined to hurl boulders?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/165260/52137), [If I cast the Enlarge/Reduce spell on an arrow, what weapon could it count as?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/143385/52137)

Comment: If you are going to use F=ma, can you explain the reason that you don't also use [conservation of momentum](https://www.physicsclassroom.com/class/momentum/Lesson-2/Momentum-Conservation-Principle) in your physics emulation?  (M1V1 = M2V2 being the simple form that relationship takes)

Comment: @Someone_Evil I'm marking those as dupes until OP suggests what the differences are.

Comment: @Someone_Evil thank you very much but none of them tackles the question to this scale.  As a DM I would argue that the arrow was shot with its current weight and since the shooter hasn't had experience with such large arrows the shot would go short...

Comment: @KorvinStarmast I wasn't fully aware of this equation I have to admit, it's been some time since I've been n contact with physics at all...well that sounds weird. So by all means please help me out here, if my question end up to be a lesson in physics for me I am willing to take it. I mean for game terms we have to brake it down anyway Yonkers stick with a sling or a short is which would be a d6. So if the projectile can keep its momentum whilst weighing 8 times its former weight the DMG should equal 8d6 right? And now I hope to learn something from you sir. ^^

Comment: I'll get with you in chat a bit later.

Comment: @Visitmytent What is the scale the others aren't tackling this to? There's definitely room for this not being a dupe, I'd just like to understand what distinction you're making.

Comment: For example, one of the answers to related questions [also addresses that same thing I mentioned](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/165556/22566) - for the moment, the dupe assessment seems to fit based on the spell and the enlarge/reduce.  As I thought through this while driving this morning, I realized that we have two or three unknowns already when trying to set up the physics problem sicne the spells don't tell us about energy states.